# Adding a class to iframe body

Tags: jquery, arrays, iframe

Can anyone please help with adding new call to iframe body I am using following code and getting this error in console:

"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame"

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

setTimeout(function(){
var numItems = $('#bfpublish').length;

// var $f = window.parent.frames['bfpublish'];
var $c = $('#bfpublish').contents();
$c.find('body').addClass("newClass");

console.log(f);
}, 6000);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://birdeye.com/embed/v4/152208062848198/8/3585104729"></script><div id="bf-revz-widget-3585104729" style="width: 9999px !important;"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the `<ifrane>`?

Comment: @zer00ne ifrmae is created after page is loaded as you can these in the dom.

Comment: If you made a [mcve] then yes, I could see the DOM. As the OP code is now, it could be anything. I have no idea if you did anything wrong or right. It is a waste of time to assume things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the content of an iframe if the URL provided to the iframe isn't from the same domain.

It would be too risky if a parent website could track what's inside an iframe from a different domain.

You can find more information about this by reading about the same-origin policy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy